# How do I transfer ownership of a Trade Post?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

With the `titleowner` console command, I can transfer ownership of land by transferring titles. However, I don't see any titles for trade posts, so I can't use this method to transfer ownership of a trade post. Is there any other way to change the owner of an existing trade post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do so with any console command. Trade posts are not actually a "title" - they're a property of the province that gets set to the current owner. You'll need to edit the save game (make sure the checkbox for compression is disabled) by opening it in a text editor.

Figure out the province number (refer to the files `\history\provinces\*.txt`)
OR
Figure out the top level holding name (b_whatever)

For example, Venice is `356` and `b_venezia`

Search for that and look for the section that looks like this:

```
356=
{
    name="Venezia"
    culture=italian
    religion=catholic
    b_venezia=
    {
        <holding data>
    }
    <more holdings>
    tradepost=
    {
        type=trade_post
        date="1.1.1"
        build_time="1.1.1"
        owner=32128
        <more data>
    }
    <more data>
}
```

You would then edit the owner to someone else.